# Garbage collection of pointers / foreign pointers during initialization

Tags: haskell, memory, garbage-collection, ghc

I'm creating a buffer using `mallocByteString` from `Data.ByteString.Internal`.

And while writing to it, at some point I may realize I haven't allocated enough memory, so I allocate a bigger buffer and use that instead.
This process (realloc, copy over, forget about old ptr) can happen many times.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Storable
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BSI


test :: IO ()
test = do
  let capacity = 1024
  foreignPtr <- BSI.mallocByteString capacity
  withForeignPtr foreignPtr $ \ptr -> do
    poke @Word8 ptr 0
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 1) 1
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 2) 2
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 3) 3
    -- etc

    -- oops, 1024 bytes isn't going to be enough
    foreignPtr' <- BSI.mallocByteString (capacity * 2)
    withForeignPtr foreignPtr' $ \ptr' -> do
      BSI.memcpy ptr ptr' capacity

      -- poke ptr', poke ptr', poke ptr'
```

My question is:  once I copy over things from `ptr` to `ptr'`, what happens to the old `ptr` and `foreignPtr`?

Does it become electable for garbage collection, even though the `withForeignPtr` continuation is still executing?
Do I need to somehow free it?

I'm worried that, if I have to realloc 10 times, I'll have 9 buffers hogging unnecessary memory.

Comment: I am not an expert on these libraries, but I'd think the foreignPtr is not forgotten until you leave from the `withForeignPtr`.

Comment: It looks like you can use `finalizeForeignPtr` to force one to be deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've restructured the code so that I back out of `withForeignPtr` when the buffer is full **and then**  realloc/copy over:

```hs
test2 :: IO ()
test2 = do
  let capacity = 1024
  foreignPtr <- BSI.mallocByteString capacity
  withForeignPtr foreignPtr $ \ptr -> do
    poke @Word8 ptr 0
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 1) 1
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 2) 2
    poke @Word8 (ptr `plusPtr` 3) 3
    -- etc

    -- oops, 1024 bytes isn't going to be enough
    return ()

  foreignPtr' <- BSI.mallocByteString (capacity * 2)
  withForeignPtr foreignPtr' $ \ptr' -> do
    withForeignPtr foreignPtr $ \ptr ->
      BSI.memcpy ptr ptr' capacity

    poke @Word8 (ptr' `plusPtr` capacity) 0
    poke @Word8 (ptr' `plusPtr` (capacity + 1)) 1
    poke @Word8 (ptr' `plusPtr` (capacity + 2)) 2
```

I believe, this way, the GC will be able to clean up old pointers.